# Dedekind complete model

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

Prove that there is no first order theory $T$ in $ L=\{<\}$ such that for every linearly order set $A$, $A$ is a model of $T$ iff $A$ is Dedekind complete.

Comment: Can you remind me the definition of Dedekind complete? What have you tried?

Comment: Dedekind complete is the least-upper-bound property.

Comment: I have just post the answer. Thankfully it was the same definition. Are you familiar with ultraproducts?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $T$ is a first-order theory in the language $L=\{<\}$ such that $(A,<)\models T$ if and only if $(A,<)$ is Dedekind complete.

Let $T_0$ be the theory of dense linear orders without end points (i.e., the set of all sentences $\phi$ deduced from the axioms establishing that $<$ is a dense linear order without end points). It is known that $T_0$ is complete as it is $\omega$-categorical (every countable model is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q},<)$.

Let $T_1=Th(\mathbb{R},<)$. Since $(\mathbb{R},<)$ is Dedekind complete, we have $T\subseteq T_1$. On the other hand, since $T_0$ is complete and $(\mathbb{R},<)$ is also a dense linear order without end points, we have that $T_1=T_0$. Hence $T\subseteq T_0$, which implies that $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ is Dedekind complete, a contradiction.

Comment: Maybe you should put $T_0 '$ as the set of formulas $\phi$ with $T_0 \models \phi$ (or equivalently, $T_0' = Th(\Bbb{Q}, <)$). Indeed as it stands, $T_0$ here only has finitely many elements, whereas $T_1$ has infinitely many, and so although "$T_1=T_0$" is understandable, it is false.

Comment: Corrected! I make this mistake all the time as I do not separate a theory (list of sentences) from all the sentences that it can deduce. In other words, for me two theories can be distinguished only if their collection of models are different.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the following definition of Dedekind complete:

> **Definition:** $(A,<)$ is Dedekind complete if every non-empty
>   $S\subseteq A$ that is bounded above has a supremum in $A$.

Suppose $T$ is a first-order theory in $L=\{<\}$ such that for every linear order $\mathcal{A}=(A,<)$, $\mathcal{A}\models T$ if and only if $\mathcal{A}$ is Dedekind complete.

If you are familiar with ultraproducts, a possible answer is this one:

---

Consider the structures $\mathcal{A}_n=(\mathbb{R},<)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $\mathcal{U}$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$. Finally, consider $\mathcal{A}:=\prod_{\mathcal{U}}\mathcal{A}_n$, the ultraproduct of the structures $(\mathcal{A}_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$ with respect to $\mathcal{U}$. By Los' theorem, since $\mathcal{A}_n\models T$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (as $(\mathbb{R},<)$ is Dedekind complete), we have that $\mathcal{A}\models T$, and so $\mathcal{A}$ is Dedekind complete.

Consider the set given by $S=\{\overline{c}_k:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ where $\overline{c}_k=\left[1-\frac{1}{k},1-\frac{1}{k},\ldots\right]_{\mathcal{U}}\in \mathcal{A}$. Notice that $\mathcal{A}\models \overline{c}_i<\overline{c}_j\leq 1$ for all $i<j$, and so $S$ is an increasing sequence which is bounded above. Let $\overline{a}$ be the supremum of $S$ in $\mathcal{A}$, with $\alpha=[a_n]_{\mathcal{U}}$. By Los' theorem, as $\overline{c}_k<\overline{a}$, we have that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$, the set $X_k=\{n\in\mathbb{N}: 1-\frac{1}{k}<a_n\}\in\mathcal{U}$.

For every $n\in X_k$, let $b_{n,k}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $1-\frac{1}{k}<b_{n,k}<a_n$, and finally put $\overline{b}=[b_{n,n}]_{\mathcal{U}}$. Then, for a fix $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $1-\frac{1}{k}<b_{n,k}\leq b_{n,n}<a_n$ whenever $n\in X_k\cap [k,+\infty)=X_k\cap (\mathbb{N}\setminus \{1,\ldots,k\})\in\mathcal{U}$, and by Los' theorem, $\overline{c}_k<\overline{b}<\overline{a}$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

In other words, $\overline{b}$ is an upper bound of the set $S$, with $\overline{b}<\overline{a}=\sup S$, a contradiction.

---

Comment: Funny, it seems that for once an ultraproduct construction can't be replaced by a compactness argument.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slight variation of Wore's argument: Suppose that $T$ would characterize Dedekind complete linear orders.

Let $T^*$ be $T$ together with $\operatorname{DLONE}$ - the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints. Now $T^*$ characterizes Dedekind complete dense linear orders without endpoints and is consistent with infinite models (as $(\mathbb R;<)$ is such a model).

Hence, by Löwenheim-Skolem, it has a countable model $(X; \prec)$. It follows, by the $\aleph_0$-categoricity of $\operatorname{DLONE}$, that $(X; \prec) \cong (\mathbb Q; <) \models T^*$. Contradiction!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can make a compactness argument work - using [Barwise's compactness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barwise_compactness_theorem) but I don't want to check all the details right now (which I would have to, since I'm not at all experienced with the applications of this beautiful result).